# Angularjs calling restful api (post) without success bad request

Tags: angularjs, json, rest, basic-authentication, restful-authentication

I have to call a restful API with basic auth "i think the auth is working)"
that needs this special custom header: **"X-AppGlu-Environment: staging"** I don't know how to put the header" then I need to post to one URL, data with this format:

```
Body:

{
  "params": {
   "stopName": "what you want search"
 }
}
```

Let's see my code at moment "it's not structured yet"

controller:

```
'use strict';

 angular.module('myApp', ['base64'])
 .controller('transportController', function($scope, $http, $base64){
$scope.$watch('search', function() {
  fetch();
});



function fetch(){

var data = {
  "params": {
   "stopName": $scope.search
 }
}

  $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
  var encoded = $base64.encode("xxxx:xxxx");
  $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ' + encoded;
  $http.post("the url", data)
 .then(function(response){ $scope.details = response.data; });

  }

  });
```

view:

```
    <div class="input-group search-bar">
      <input type="text" ng-model="search" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 800 }" onclick="select()" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter destiny" autofocus />
      <span class="input-group-addon bar-style"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span>
```

I receive a error 400 bad request when i try to search for something, i think is something with the format of the object i'm trying to send, but if is, i don't know what to change.

Comment: I would start by making use of the dev tools in your browser. You should be able to find the post under the network tab. Inspect the post so you can see what you are sending out.

Comment: Is working now i changed to this structure

Answer (score 0):

Is working now i changed to this structure

```
function fetch(){

var data = { 
      "params":{
        "stopName": "%"+$scope.search+"%"
    }
}

var encoded = $base64.encode("xxxx:xxxx");
$http({
  url: "url",
  headers : {
    "X-AppGlu-Environment":"staging",
    "Authorization": "Basic "+encoded,
    "Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  },
  method: 'POST',
  data: { 
    "params":{
      "stopName": "%"+$scope.search+"%"
    }
  }
}).then(function(response){ 
    $scope.details = response.data.rows; 
});


 // $http.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=" + $scope.search)
  //.then(function(response){ $scope.related = response.data; });
}
```